# Unable to surf to twitter with chrome: NET: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: macos, twitter, google-chrome-extension

After I installed Ghostery into Chrome (MacOS 10.0.5, Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit), fully up to date), suddenly Chrome can't surf to twitter.com without complaining that the Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3 is invalid. I removed this extension, restarted Chrome, even restarted the computer, but still the issue remains.

Safari also complains, but interestingly, Firefox remains able to access twitter.com without complaints. So this implies to me that the certs as stored by Keychain Access are ok.

Has anybody seen this/know how to fix? So far, I've checked that the computer's time is fine (some posts say that might be an issue), and verified everything about accessing my twitter account with Firefox is fine.

If there's some version of the certs stored in Chrome and Safari I can clear to fix this, that'd be great, but clearing the generic content cache doesn't seem to do anything.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked through this one posted on Google product forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/SE3sKXg0iFQ/DYIXNEcVEgEJ

Comment: No I hadn't found that, but I followed those instructions and it worked! Thank you so much! Hope this helps others-- you rock!

Answer (score 6):

I have just tested it and solved it, the reply is in @gui47's comment:

- go to your keychain
- remove the `Verisign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5` certificates from `sessions` or `login`
- close everything, reboot

no idea why it happened so suddenly

Comment: hours of googling and ineffective fixes, this here did the trick

Comment: What would cause this step to be required for some Mac users?

Comment: for me it happened after I generated certificates for an app in the app store.

Comment: Thank you. I updated to OS X El Capitan and had this issue. Your solution fixed it.

Comment: for future searches:
After updating OSX El Capitan, many SSL sites stopped working (Asana / Hotels.com ...etc) .  AppStore also stopped working.
This fixed it !
THX !!

Answer (score 0):

If nothing you do solves the problem, what I discovered is that my corporate masters operate a man in the middle attack against all their employees using Blue Coat security (https://www.bluecoat.com/products/ssl-decryption-visibility-and-management). Your web browser will likely have your employer's dodgy certificate installed as a trusted root certificate, so for the vast majority of HTTPS web sites, the behaviour of this rather nasty piece of software will be transparent, however if the site uses HSTS and your web browser (such as recent versions of Chrome) looks for it, then you will get this error.

What this means is that your employer is not to be trusted and you shouldn't be online banking at this particular workplace. It also means that your employer, rightly or wrongly doesn't trust you. My IT department brazenly denied that this is a MitM attack, which leads me to also doubt their competence if they don't know what a MitM attack is, especially when they are the MitM!

Answer (score -2):

Nothing is required.

Just clear your cache and do the following
Privacy -->Content settings -->Do not allow any site to run JavaScript

Problem solved.

Comment: ... or i could just go back to using [lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/).  or even, hey, [smoke signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_signal) were a great way to transmit information once...